# Code first approach about database change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Pretty new to all of this MVC/EF stuff and was wondering how to properly handle code first class changes.

I had a class that was point to a production database to retrieve and store information.  When defining the database context I had it pointing to a table, however I wanted it to look at a view so changed it.  It then started going a bit loopy and said about code migration.  The view existed and all was correct.

To correct this I used the SetInitializer for the context to be false in the Global.asax and all worked fine.

Sorry I don't have my code to hand to paste and don't know it well enough to write off the top of my head.

Anyhow, my question is I thought the hole point of the class and context as to define it, if I changed that in code then wouldn't that be enough?  Migration seemed to want to change or update the production database!

Is there some meta data behind the model class and context that snaps shots the data base in code first that is accessible that should be changed or is the SetInitializer the correct path to use in this scenario?

TO be sure I am using Code first I basically manually code the model and then define it using DbSet<> in the database context

Comment: If you're doing code first to an existing database, you may want to reverse engineer the classes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx  Otherwise, you can generate a migration (add-migration) and inspect it for the changes EF wants to make to the database. Then you can adjust your model and comment out the Up() code on the migration before applying it.

Comment: Thanks, but what if you are changing the Db context so that DbSet<Model> TableA to be DbSet<Model> vwTableA so it looks at a view not a table.  The view exists so no database changes are required.  

If it was all set up without using the wizards but manually coded, I read somewhere that the only fix was using the SetInitializer.  I had some errors trying the migration.

It would seem logical that on the first build VS creates some sort of background reference class linking the context the database and that why you get the migration error when you change the object it points to on the database

Comment: Just changing the variable name won't make it use the view, assuming you mean that you mapped it to a view instead of a table then EF will generate an internal model for comparison. If something is off, it will complain that you need to run a migration. Trying to manually get hand coded classes and relationships to match would be difficult. That is why they have tools to reverse engineer the database. Once you get a clean migration it will work as you expect - code changes drive database changes.

Comment: You could of course add a migration, comment out some/all of the Up() code and update and EF will assume you are in sync until you try something that isn't compatible with the database.

Comment: Code first means you are mapping your model class to your database, so if you make any changes to your model class, you have to do a add-migration and then update-database, so that the database and your model class are properly mapped and up to date. I am not sure what you mean by view, but the model class is definitely not something associated with the view, maybe you mean viewmodel class? viewmodel class is not the same as model class, model class is to database, viewmodel class is to view, although two looks very similar, they are not to be mixed

Comment: Hi Eric,

Sorry by view I meant a SQL view.  As that already existed when I changed the DBContext I was confused as to why it needed migration scripts?

As mentioned, when I added

Database.SetInitializer<DataBaseContext>(null);

All worked fine and the data is returned!